# How to assign a function to an operator?

Tags: pascal, operator-keyword

so i have a really simple function in my unit:

```
Function AzonosE(Const n1,n2:TNap):Boolean;
Begin
    AzonosE:=n1=n2;
End;
```

i'd like to assign the('=') operator to this function, so that i can use  this function in my main program this way : `if n1=n2` (n1,n2:TNap;)

Comment: Seems that you are looking for operator overloading. Take a look [here](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse89.html#x191-20100015.5)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

That's not standard Pascal functionality. OTOH, afaik neither is "CONST". You need to better specify your dialect/compiler.

In the case of Free Pascal, Niculare's reference to the relevant manual page is correct. It is afaik FPC specific though. For more practical applications it is best to have a look at the ucomplex unit in the RTL that defines a complex type.

Delphi afaik only allows it as part of structured type:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Operator_Overloading_%28Delphi%29